# Postgresql table size different on different sharding nodes

Tags: postgresql

We have application where we are using PostgreSQL database as backend. Due to huge traffic we have implemented sharding solution (having three shard nodes) at application level to use all three shard nodes. But now one of our table on all three shard nodes have different size but having same row count. Table is having some configuration data and is used for read for different components. Size of table is 2MB on shard-1, 122MB on sshard-2 and 18 MB on shard-3 whereas count is 305 rows in all shards.

Please help us to find what will be reason behind this

Comment: Maybe table bloat. Did you do a `vacuum full` for that table on the all shards? See here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat for some queries to investigate

Comment: Is this PostgresXL (horizontal sharding) or Postgress 10 (vertical sharding) or something else entirely ?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328)  (also posted to: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/185163/1822 where it actually belongs)

Comment: Thanks for help.

Comment: what would be possible reason for table bloat.